# Click method is not working with chrome emulator

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, mobile-emulator

Below are the details of my setup:

> chrome=67.0.3396.87, 
>   chromedriver=2.40.565498, 
>   selenium version-2.53.0

Below is the emulator code-

```
public ChromeOptions getChromeEmulators(int width, int height) {
    Map<String, Object> deviceMetrics = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    try {
        deviceMetrics.put("width", width);           
        deviceMetrics.put("height", height);
        deviceMetrics.put("pixelRatio", 3.0);
        mobileEmulation.put("deviceMetrics", deviceMetrics);
        mobileEmulation.put("userAgent",
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) 
AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile 
Safari/535.19");
       chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackStarce();
    }
    return chromeOptions;
}
```

The click option is not working with chrome emulator, but it works on chrome browser with above versions. Can someone help?

Comment: try by upgrading your selenium to latest version

Comment: I fixed your code formatting, but you are still missing additional information. Please read [mcve] for details.

Comment: What is an error, its giving

Comment: Example steps are-

    'driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys(password);    
   driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("SiteNavigationIcon")).click();'
  
        It clicks on login button in above steps but nothing happens(homepage not displayed after login). So giving error on next element click that "Unable to locate element".

Comment: Tried with JavascriptExecutor it works. But in every script click method need to replace with  JavascriptExecutor script click.
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",element);
  
  Need to try with updating selenium version. But still if there is any other way let me know.

Comment: Tried with selenium versions but no luck without javascript-
     selenium version-3.0.0
     selenium version-3.1.0
     selenium version-3.2.0
     selenium version-3.12.0
     selenium version-3.13.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue of chromedriver in existence since the past few versions. No fix yet. At this point, the only workaround is to use chromerdriver : 2.33.506120 + chrome : 61.0.3163.79

Refer to the below bugs :

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2144&desc=2

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2172

Alternatively, u can try JavascriptExecutor (though this is not much preferred)

```
JavascriptExecutor script click. JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) 
driver; js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",element);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have downgraded chrome browser version to 65 and chromedriver to 2.38  and it started working.